# R Interpret coefficient from Survreg(dist="gaussian")

Tags: r, survival, regression-coefficients

I was wondering if anyone could help me on how to interpret the coefficient from an analysis I have carried out in R (`survival` package).

The data is right censored, the dependent variable (time to event) was modelled under the gaussian distribution and the independent variable is a categorical variable (3 categories).

my output is as follows:

```
coeff   se     p-value
-0.107  0.048  2.7x10-2
```

Can anyone tell me how to interpret this coefficient under the following model?

Comment: How is it that you have a 3-level categorical variable, but only 1 coeff? I suspect you haven't provided enough information for this question to be answerable.

Answer (score 1):

You've not provided an awful lot of information for us to go on (such as the full code you typed and the full output), but the output is telling you that the effect of your predictor variable statistically significantly reduces the hazard of the average observation of experiencing the event (whatever that may be).

If this isn't enough of an answer, you'll need to say more. I'd suggest that reading a good primer on how to interpret the statistics of survival analysis models wouldn't go amiss. One such is Paul Allison's second edition of "Event History and Survival Analysis" (07-46) published by Sage in their QASS series this year.

Comment: Patrick didn't ask the question, he just edited it so addressing him in your answer was a bit misdirected. The OP is C_S.